# Import data from Excel and process it and export it to Excel using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to import data form Excel into the SQL server and process it by executing the stored proc and export it back to Excel.

I am able to do this task , but the problem is that the package hangs and dose not let me do anything when i click on anything. I simple words it takes a long time to open.

I have set the ValidateExternalMetadata property to false (for all the components inside the data flow task) and DelayValidation property to true (at the task level).

Basically i am experiencing a huge delay or hanging particularly when i touch the Excel destination.

I have used only one Excel connection for both import and export. Dose this cause any issue ? Can some one point me to the right way to resolving this.

Comment: After you import the excel data, are you exporting it back to the same file, or to a different file?

Comment: Since you're using the same Excel connection for both the import and export, it will be the same Excel file.  Are you exporting to a different worksheet in that file?  Also, why are you exporting back to the same Excel file instead of a different one?